# Simplify this: if (xyz) // do something and same on resize

Tags: javascript, mobile, resize, simplify

I find myself creating code for mobile and then wrapping the same block in a resize function.

Is there a more condensed / more eleganter way of writing something like this:

```
if ($(window).width() <= 767) {
    // do something
}
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 767) {
        // do same thing as above
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 767) {
    // do something
  }
});

// call resize once at startup
$(function() {
  $(window).trigger("resize");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
function doSomething() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 767) {
  // do something
  }
}

$(window).on("resize size-init", doSomething).trigger("size-init");
```

It's also probably a good idea to do as much as you can via CSS media queries.

Comment: Thank... that works. I marked maxime's answer as the answer because it's a more global approach and better for this particular application.